# Room / SQLite query with min(...) without returning any result if nothing found

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Currently stuck at a SQL roadblock and I am having no luck in finding any answers for my issue due to how generic the relating words are.

I have two queries that appear to be the exact same thing, but yield a different outcome.

For the sake of these examples assume that there is NO entry with `id 123` and `MyTable` has the following columns: `id`, `time`, and `data`.

One query is for an entry that does not exist with all the columns

```sql
SELECT id, data, time FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123
```

which returns no results.

The other query is also for an entry that does not exist with all the columns

```sql
SELECT id, data, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123
```

which returns one result where every column has the value `null`

Example of this scenario from Android Studio:

returns no results, as desired
[image]

returns one result with all columns as null
[image]

same issue happens even if I name the column with the same name
[image]

I am trying to achieve the same behavior in the second query as the first one; if there are no results then return no results, instead of returning one result with all columns with null for values.

I understand I can work around this by doing a sub-query and querying that, but I would prefer to use a single query as simple as the ones above.

Is this not possible or is there a way that I can achieve that in Android Room Library / SQLite?

EDIT: The question was initially incorrect, thanks to users in the comments I realized the issue happens whenever using `min(...)` in the query so I updated the question to reflect the correct problem.

Comment: To return anything but a single value the function associated with the query has to return an object. The results may depend upon the objects returned. So you should edit your question to include the functions associated with the queries and the respective objects returned.

Comment: What do you mean by: *...returns one result where every column has the value null*? If there is no id=123 then both queries do not return any results.

Comment: I assume OP asks with a different context than querying a normal table, but a table valued function which probably somehow results in a row of nulls... easiest way around this is to add a null check to the where clause to filter out the offending row, e.g. `coalesce(id,time,data) is not null` but this is only based on an assumption... would be helpful if OP clarifies the question

Comment: @forpas I mean that when I query with the specified columns then the result returns an object with all fields set to null, but if I use the * then it returns no results

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Unsure of how I can clarify, but I will at least include some examples from my use case and screenshots

Comment: *...the result returns an object with all fields set to null* this is not possible if there is no id=123. Can you reproduce this with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_)?

Comment: @forpas I believe I might actually misread the query, the issue is only present if there is a min(column) included in the query, for example: `SELECT id, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123`. I will update the question to reflect that correctly.

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual case, apologies for misinterpreting the actual cause, I did not realize it was limited to when using `min(...)`.

Comment: @forpas I am afraid I do not know how to use that website in order to provide with a fiddle as an example of my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT id, data, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123
```

is an [aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#generation_of_the_set_of_result_rows) and as such it will **always** return **exactly** 1 row.

If you want it to return nothing in case the condition in the `WHERE` clause fails, use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT id, data, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123
EXCEPT
SELECT null, null, null; -- as many null columns as the main selection
```

or, use a *non-standard SQL* feature of SQL with a `HAVING` clause in an aggregate query without a `GROUP BY` clause (which will not work in other databases):

```
SELECT id, data, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123
HAVING id IS NOT NULL;
```

or, with a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT id, data, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123
GROUP BY id
HAVING id IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IPYCllX7).

Comment: That worked perfectly and I can live with that compromise. Unless anyone else has a better way of doing this while considering the comments in my question then this is the answer I have picked for my problem. Also I learned something new today, so thanks for explaining why that was happening.

Comment: @Shadow check an alternative solution in my edited answer, which as I mention is non-standard and works only in SQLite.

Comment: unfortunately `HAVING` is not accepted in Android Studio query and Room Library, so that one is not an option for me. It would be great to just use that single column instead of having to write all of them in the `except select ...`.

Comment: so it seems like `HAVING` can be used, but it MUST be accompanied by `GROUP BY...` as per their documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/db/SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder#having

Comment: @Shadow you can add a GROUP BY clause without affecting the functionality of this query: `SELECT id, data, min(time) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123 GROUP BY id
HAVING id IS NOT NULL;`: https://dbfiddle.uk/xwzRUphx

Comment: Done, perfect! Can you update your answer with that one? I am sure others looking for this will find that to be the most useful one.